# Is making weird faces to make a friend laugh permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, adab

Is making weird faces to make a friend (of same gender) laugh allowed in Islam?

I just wanted to know about it because it seems to me that it may be disliked. But I wanted to know the Islamic perspective (of Ahlus Sunnah wal Jama'ah) on it rather than my assumption.

Comment: It would be easier for the community to answer if you could provide additional details such as why you think it's not permissible.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I provided that.